# Not able to cast Bool value correctly from Api response Swift 5

Tags: json, swift

Below is the value from Api response in the form of Json:

```
isFavorite = true;
```

This is the way getting it in model class:

declaration:

```
var isFavorite:Bool = false
init(json:NSDictionary?)
{
    if json != nil
    {
       self.isFavorite = ((json?.object(forKey: "isFavorite")) != nil)
    }
}
```

this way always getting "true"

Earlier tried this way:

```
self.isFavorite = (json?.object(forKey: "isFavorite") as? Bool ?? false)
```

this way always getting "false"

I am not getting what is wrong i am doing in parsing this Bool

Update: Api response

```
isFavorite = true;
```

Comment: What is this `json` variable show in your code? What is its type? How is it initialized? Show that code in your question.

Comment: Why are you using `NSDictionary` in Swift? Use a proper Swift dictionary.

Comment: can it work with NSDictionary. I think it should because other values String and Int i am able to parse only Bool is giving problem. So, only because of Bool value i think it is not wise to change the whole.

Comment: In an `NSDictionary`, numbers and bools are actually wrapped in `NSNumber` instances. It's a really poor choice to use this in Swift. There are much better and simpler ways to parse JSON in Swift that give you proper Swift dictionaries and arrays and bools.

Comment: What does the data you receive from the API look like before you add it to the dictionary? Could you add an example of the raw data for “isFavorite”?

Comment: added above is raw received from api response

Answer (score 1):

All JSON types in Swift are value types. So reference type `NSDictionary` is discouraged (anyway).

The native Swift way is

```
let isFavorite : Bool

init(json: [String:Any]) {
    self.isFavorite = json["isFavorite"] as? Bool ?? false
}
```

But from the given (`NSDictionary`) output `isFavorite = true;` the value is apparently `String`. In this case you have to write

```
let isFavorite : Bool

init(json: [String:Any]) {
    if let favorite = json["isFavorite"] as? String, favorite == "true" {
         self.isFavorite = true
      } else {
         self.isFavorite = false
    }
}
```

Comment: it is also giving false only

Comment: Then there's something wrong with the dictionary and the value for `isFavorite` is not a Bool. Please edit your question and add the relevant part of the JSON.

Comment: i don't think so, please have a look:
po json!["isFavorite"] 
▿ Optional<Any>
  - some : true
po json!["isFavorite"] as? Bool ?? false
false

Comment: it is bool for sure

Comment: `Optional<Any>` can be also Int or even String. For example `"true"` is not Bool

Comment: You are right i guess it's not bool coming from api response, please check the updated question

Comment: i have already mentioned api response in beginning of the question, isn't it bool or something else? please guide

Comment: please delete your answer i want to delete question as it is not clear with the requirements exactly.

Comment: have fixed it myself by using "
            self.fav = json?.object(forKey: "isFavorite") as? String ?? ""
            self.isFavorite = (self.fav as NSString).boolValue

Comment: Bridging to `NSString` is *unswifty* like using `NSDictionary`